# Checksum issue CRC16CCITT

Tags: java, c

I have the following C-code which I am trying to re-write in java.
I would like to see similar outputs in both of them but I am getting different outputs.
This is for computation of checksum.

Here is the C-code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*~+:CRC Table*/
static unsigned short crctab[256] =
{
0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7,
0x8108, 0x9129, 0xA14A, 0xB16B, 0xC18C, 0xD1AD, 0xE1CE, 0xF1EF,
0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52B5, 0x4294, 0x72F7, 0x62D6,
0x9339, 0x8318, 0xB37B, 0xA35A, 0xD3BD, 0xC39C, 0xF3FF, 0xE3DE,
0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64E6, 0x74C7, 0x44A4, 0x5485,
0xA56A, 0xB54B, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xE5EE, 0xF5CF, 0xC5AC, 0xD58D,
0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76D7, 0x66F6, 0x5695, 0x46B4,
0xB75B, 0xA77A, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xF7DF, 0xE7FE, 0xD79D, 0xC7BC,
0x48C4, 0x58E5, 0x6886, 0x78A7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
0xC9CC, 0xD9ED, 0xE98E, 0xF9AF, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xA90A, 0xB92B,
0x5AF5, 0x4AD4, 0x7AB7, 0x6A96, 0x1A71, 0x0A50, 0x3A33, 0x2A12,
0xDBFD, 0xCBDC, 0xFBBF, 0xEB9E, 0x9B79, 0x8B58, 0xBB3B, 0xAB1A,
0x6CA6, 0x7C87, 0x4CE4, 0x5CC5, 0x2C22, 0x3C03, 0x0C60, 0x1C41,
0xEDAE, 0xFD8F, 0xCDEC, 0xDDCD, 0xAD2A, 0xBD0B, 0x8D68, 0x9D49,
0x7E97, 0x6EB6, 0x5ED5, 0x4EF4, 0x3E13, 0x2E32, 0x1E51, 0x0E70,
0xFF9F, 0xEFBE, 0xDFDD, 0xCFFC, 0xBF1B, 0xAF3A, 0x9F59, 0x8F78,
0x9188, 0x81A9, 0xB1CA, 0xA1EB, 0xD10C, 0xC12D, 0xF14E, 0xE16F,
0x1080, 0x00A1, 0x30C2, 0x20E3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
0x83B9, 0x9398, 0xA3FB, 0xB3DA, 0xC33D, 0xD31C, 0xE37F, 0xF35E,
0x02B1, 0x1290, 0x22F3, 0x32D2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
0xB5EA, 0xA5CB, 0x95A8, 0x8589, 0xF56E, 0xE54F, 0xD52C, 0xC50D,
0x34E2, 0x24C3, 0x14A0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
0xA7DB, 0xB7FA, 0x8799, 0x97B8, 0xE75F, 0xF77E, 0xC71D, 0xD73C,
0x26D3, 0x36F2, 0x0691, 0x16B0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
0xD94C, 0xC96D, 0xF90E, 0xE92F, 0x99C8, 0x89E9, 0xB98A, 0xA9AB,
0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18C0, 0x08E1, 0x3882, 0x28A3,
0xCB7D, 0xDB5C, 0xEB3F, 0xFB1E, 0x8BF9, 0x9BD8, 0xABBB, 0xBB9A,
0x4A75, 0x5A54, 0x6A37, 0x7A16, 0x0AF1, 0x1AD0, 0x2AB3, 0x3A92,
0xFD2E, 0xED0F, 0xDD6C, 0xCD4D, 0xBDAA, 0xAD8B, 0x9DE8, 0x8DC9,
0x7C26, 0x6C07, 0x5C64, 0x4C45, 0x3CA2, 0x2C83, 0x1CE0, 0x0CC1,
0xEF1F, 0xFF3E, 0xCF5D, 0xDF7C, 0xAF9B, 0xBFBA, 0x8FD9, 0x9FF8,
0x6E17, 0x7E36, 0x4E55, 0x5E74, 0x2E93, 0x3EB2, 0x0ED1, 0x1EF0
};

void convert_toASCII (char *buffer, int value)
{
/*
Function converts given 'value' into a 4 byte
ASCII-HEX-String (with leading zeros) to 'buffer[]'
Parameter: char *buffer, int value
Returns: none
*/
static unsigned char hex_num[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
static unsigned char i; /* HV */
i = (char)((value & 0xf000) >> 12);
*buffer = (char)(hex_num[i]);
++buffer;
i = (char)((value & 0x0f00) >> 8);
*buffer = (char)(hex_num[i]);
++buffer;
i = (char)((value & 0x00f0) >> 4);
*buffer = (char)(hex_num[i]);
++buffer;
i = (char)(value & 0x000f);
*buffer = (char)(hex_num[i]);
}

void calc_crc(unsigned char *databuffer,unsigned int length)
{
/*~+:Modulname: calc_crc */
/*~+:Calculate serial CRC (according CCITT ) */
/*~+:The serial CRC16 is calculated for a certain length (int length) */
/*~+:over bytes in buffer (char databuffer[]) */
/*~+: */
/*~+:Input: *databuffer pointer to data string */
/*~+: laenge number of chars to build CRC for */
/*~+:Output: the CRC will be added in ASCII characters ( 4 chars) */
/*~+: at the end of the given string and terminated with '\0' */
/*~+: The buffer must be able to handle these additional */
/*~+: 5 characters */
static unsigned char tmp;
static unsigned int crc,zaehler;
crc = 0;
for (zaehler = 0;zaehler < length ;zaehler ++)
{
tmp=(unsigned char) (crc>>8) ;
crc=(crc<<8) ^ crctab[tmp] ^ *databuffer;
databuffer++;
}

printf("%u", crc);


/* convert crc -> ASCII */
/* append to string */
convert_toASCII (databuffer, crc);
}

void main(void)
{
static char Data[] = {"abcdefghij"};
static char buffer[64];
strcpy(buffer,Datensatz);
printf("Data : %s \n\r",&buffer[0]);
calc_crc(buffer,10);
printf("CRC : %s \n\r",&buffer[10]);
printf("Data mit CRC: %s \n\r",&buffer[0]);
}
```

The java code that I have written is:

```
public final class Checksum
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String checksumString = "abcdefghij";
        final int checksum = calculateCRC16CCITTChecksum(checksumString);
        System.out.println("Checksum integer value:" + checksum);
        System.out.println("Checksum value in Hex:" + Integer.toHexString(checksum));
    }

    /**
     * @param frame The frame for whose checksum has to be calculated.
     * @return The calculated checksum.
     */
    private final static int calculateCRC16CCITTChecksum(final String frame)
    {
        final int[] CRC16_Lookup = {0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7, 0x8108, 0x9129, 0xA14A, 0xB16B, 0xC18C, 0xD1AD, 0xE1CE, 0xF1EF, 0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252,
                0x52B5, 0x4294, 0x72F7, 0x62D6, 0x9339, 0x8318, 0xB37B, 0xA35A, 0xD3BD, 0xC39C, 0xF3FF, 0xE3DE, 0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64E6, 0x74C7, 0x44A4, 0x5485, 0xA56A, 0xB54B, 0x8528,
                0x9509, 0xE5EE, 0xF5CF, 0xC5AC, 0xD58D, 0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76D7, 0x66F6, 0x5695, 0x46B4, 0xB75B, 0xA77A, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xF7DF, 0xE7FE, 0xD79D, 0xC7BC, 0x48C4, 0x58E5,
                0x6886, 0x78A7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823, 0xC9CC, 0xD9ED, 0xE98E, 0xF9AF, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xA90A, 0xB92B, 0x5AF5, 0x4AD4, 0x7AB7, 0x6A96, 0x1A71, 0x0A50, 0x3A33, 0x2A12, 0xDBFD,
                0xCBDC, 0xFBBF, 0xEB9E, 0x9B79, 0x8B58, 0xBB3B, 0xAB1A, 0x6CA6, 0x7C87, 0x4CE4, 0x5CC5, 0x2C22, 0x3C03, 0x0C60, 0x1C41, 0xEDAE, 0xFD8F, 0xCDEC, 0xDDCD, 0xAD2A, 0xBD0B, 0x8D68, 0x9D49,
                0x7E97, 0x6EB6, 0x5ED5, 0x4EF4, 0x3E13, 0x2E32, 0x1E51, 0x0E70, 0xFF9F, 0xEFBE, 0xDFDD, 0xCFFC, 0xBF1B, 0xAF3A, 0x9F59, 0x8F78, 0x9188, 0x81A9, 0xB1CA, 0xA1EB, 0xD10C, 0xC12D, 0xF14E,
                0xE16F, 0x1080, 0x00A1, 0x30C2, 0x20E3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067, 0x83B9, 0x9398, 0xA3FB, 0xB3DA, 0xC33D, 0xD31C, 0xE37F, 0xF35E, 0x02B1, 0x1290, 0x22F3, 0x32D2, 0x4235, 0x5214,
                0x6277, 0x7256, 0xB5EA, 0xA5CB, 0x95A8, 0x8589, 0xF56E, 0xE54F, 0xD52C, 0xC50D, 0x34E2, 0x24C3, 0x14A0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405, 0xA7DB, 0xB7FA, 0x8799, 0x97B8, 0xE75F,
                0xF77E, 0xC71D, 0xD73C, 0x26D3, 0x36F2, 0x0691, 0x16B0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634, 0xD94C, 0xC96D, 0xF90E, 0xE92F, 0x99C8, 0x89E9, 0xB98A, 0xA9AB, 0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827,
                0x18C0, 0x08E1, 0x3882, 0x28A3, 0xCB7D, 0xDB5C, 0xEB3F, 0xFB1E, 0x8BF9, 0x9BD8, 0xABBB, 0xBB9A, 0x4A75, 0x5A54, 0x6A37, 0x7A16, 0x0AF1, 0x1AD0, 0x2AB3, 0x3A92, 0xFD2E, 0xED0F, 0xDD6C,
                0xCD4D, 0xBDAA, 0xAD8B, 0x9DE8, 0x8DC9, 0x7C26, 0x6C07, 0x5C64, 0x4C45, 0x3CA2, 0x2C83, 0x1CE0, 0x0CC1, 0xEF1F, 0xFF3E, 0xCF5D, 0xDF7C, 0xAF9B, 0xBFBA, 0x8FD9, 0x9FF8, 0x6E17, 0x7E36,
                0x4E55, 0x5E74, 0x2E93, 0x3EB2, 0x0ED1, 0x1EF0};
        // check sum for polynomial 1.x16 + 0.x15 + 0.x14 + 0.x13 + 1.x12 + 0.x11 + 0.x10 + 0.x9 + 0.x8 + 0.x7 + 0.x6 + 1.x5 + 0.x4 + 0.x3 + 0.x2 +0.x1 + 1.x0.
        // 1.x16 - implies 1 multiplied by 'x' to the power of 16.
        int crc = 0;

        for (int i = 0, size = frame.length(); i < size; i++)
        {
            crc = (crc << 8) ^ CRC16_Lookup[(crc >> 8) & 0xFF] ^ (frame.charAt(i) & 0xFF);
        }

        return crc & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

The integer value output that I get in java code is different from what the decimal value that I get in C, even the hex string conversion in java yields different results to that of hex conversion in C.
Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for looking!!

Comment: Which implementation yields the *correct* CRC? (e.g. test with a *known-good* source). I would recommend aligning the tables the same in both versions (the C looks better with 8 values/line, IMOHO) and then doing a DIFF on them. Also, consider using a dynamically generated table... it's pretty easy.

Comment: @Rishi: I don't fire debuggers that often but that is one case where I'd have fun by firing two debuggers, side-by-side, one for Java and one for C, and do step-by-step debugging to see what's going on ; )

Comment: As far as I know all primitives in java are signed - so maybe it is just a representation problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not strictly related to an implementation problem, but I guess it's worth mentioning anyway. Keep in mind that some communication protocols require XORing the input values and output values with some value, not to mention bit or byte reflecting of the input data. This happens in Ethernet, which uses CRC-32 for the actual calculations, but the input and output data is XORed with FF..FF (so, it's NOTed), and all the bits in the input byte (or, more naturally, nibble) are reflected. Keep that in mind - the actual calculations might be alright, but there might be something you're simply not aware of in terms of mangling the data, what leads to completely different results.

Comment: Upvoted this unexplained downvote. The answer is perfectly correct. It could perhaps have made clear that this is accomplished just by changing the initial CRC value from 0 to 0xffff.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

By code inspection, one can see that in Java the CRC is limited to 16 bits before being printed in decimal (use of & 0xFFFF before returning the function). In C, the value printed is the full unsigned int, so applying the same mask should do the trick.

I can't understand why the hex values differ, though...

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am getting the same values with my code, it was just that I was missing some chars in the input string to java code when compared to C.